# How to retrieve the value of a selected cell (by click) in a reactive table?

Tags: r, shiny

I create an R shiny app that allow to enter text to implemente a clickable table. Now I would like to retrieve the value of selected cell. For now I only get the row and column number but the value of the cell appear empty. Thanks a lot for your help.

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("caption", "Saisir votre addresse", ""),
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
  mainPanel(
  width = 8,
  dataTableOutput('my_table')
  ),
  mainPanel( textOutput("selected_text") )
) 

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$my_table = DT::renderDataTable(as.data.frame(input$caption),selection = list(mode = "single", target = "cell"),options = list(paging = FALSE,searching = FALSE)) 
  
  observeEvent(input$my_table_cells_selected, {
    info <- input$my_table_cells_selected
    output$selected_text <- renderText({
      paste(info) # info[3] for value 
    }) 
  }) #Observe event
  
} # server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

EDIT : This new code is working

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  textInput("caption", "Saisir votre addresse", ""),
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4, bootswatch = "minty"),
  mainPanel(
    width = 8,
    dataTableOutput('my_table')
  ),
  mainPanel( textOutput("selected_text") )
) 

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$my_table = DT::renderDataTable(as.data.frame(input$caption),selection = list(mode = "single", target = "cell"),options = list(paging = FALSE,searching = FALSE)) 
  
  observeEvent(input$my_table_cells_selected, {
    info <- input$my_table_cells_selected
    output$selected_text <- renderText({
      as.data.frame(as.data.frame(input$caption))[info]
    }) 
  }) #Observe event
  
} # server

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I don't think `info[3]` is the value. You need to use the row and column on the underlying data.frame, like `as.data.frame(input$caption)[info[[1]], info[[2]]]`

Comment: You are right, I had been misled by this page (https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html) where it is indicated : input$tableId_cell_clicked: information about the cell being clicked of the form list(row = row_index, col = column_index, value = cell_value). So I expected to get a list whose 3rd element was the cell value.

Comment: Next time, try `print`ing `info`...